# Symmetric Bilinear Form

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form

Let $V = \mathbb{R}[x]_n$ be the real vector space of all real polynomials of degree $\leq n$.

$$\alpha(f,g,) = \int^1_0 xf(x)g(x)\,dx$$

I need to prove that this is a symmetric bilinear form on $V$. Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: So what is a symmetric bilinear form? Does $\alpha$ satisfy the axioms of a symmetric bilinear form?

Comment: if it's a symmetric matrix then it is symmetric? but I don't know how to prove that

Comment: First, show that $\alpha$ is a bilinear form. Then, show that for any $f,g \in \mathbb{R}[x]_n$, $\alpha(f, g) = \alpha(g,f)$.

Comment: I don't know how to prove that it is bilinear. I know that it has to satisfy conditions such as B(u + v, w) = B(u, w) + B(v, w) but I don't know how to apply that to this case

Comment: Here's a start.  For any $f,h,g \in \mathbb{R}[x]_n$, $\alpha(f + h, g) = \int^1_0 x(f(x) + h(x))g(x)dx = \int^1_0 (xf(x)g(x) + xh(x)g(x))dx$.  Can you go on from there?